# Password change field reset password django

Tags: python, html, django

I created a password reset system through email using django, but when I am at the password page, if I enter the password and confirmation right, it doesn't do anything just reloads the page and seems to throw in error in form.errors, but it shows this field is required (error) even though I filled it out.

In addition, how do you make it so only one email can be assigned to a user. So when registering or changing your info, the same email can't be used with two accounts.

Here is the code to my password reset page:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block head %}
    <link href="\static\accounts\css\forms.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="\static\registration\js\emailvariable.js"></script>
{% endblock %}
{% block body %}
  {% if validlink %}
    <h3 style="text-align: center">Change password</h3>
    <form id="login-form" method="post">

                {% csrf_token %}
                    <input placeholder="Password" id="id_password" name="password"
                                   type="password" class="form-control">
                    <input placeholder="Confirm Password" id="id_password2" name="password2"
                                               type="password" class="form-control">
                <div style="text-align:center;">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-dark centerbutton">Change password</button>
                </div>
                {% if form.errors %}
                    <p class=" label label-danger">
                        <div style="text-align: center">
                            {{ error | escape }}
                        </div>
                    </p>
                {% endif %}
            </form>
  {% else %}
    <p>
      The password reset link was invalid, possibly because it has already been used.
      Please request a new password reset.
    </p>
  {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: please show us some code and describe the error in detail

Comment: I must have forgotten that. I edited the post to show the code

Comment: Show your views.

Comment: Did you use the default password reset system or is this one you created yourself?

Comment: This is my own custom form, but I'm using the django password reset system.

Comment: Do you have anything like '''SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True
USE_X_FORWARDED_HOST = True
SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTOCOL', 'https')
SECURE_CONTENT_TYPE_NOSNIFF = True
SECURE_BROWSER_XSS_FILTER = True
SECURE_CONTENT_TYPE_NOSNIFF = True
SECURE_BROWSER_XSS_FILTER = True'''

This stuff can prevent secure forms from being submitted if the website is not properly configured.

Comment: Did you follow any particular tutorial for setting up password reset? There are a couple ways to do it, so that would give us a starting point.

Comment: It must to be something to do with my custom form, because if I use the default form it seems to be working fine. I didn't follow any tutorial for the actual form by the way.

Comment: Yeah, if the default form works it is presumably a template problem unless you have a custom view?

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure about your first question, but I can answer the 2nd.

```
class SignUpForm(UserCreationForm):

    def clean_email(self):
        email = self.cleaned_data.get('email')
        username = self.cleaned_data.get('username')
        if email and User.objects.filter(email=email).exclude(username=username).exists():
            raise forms.ValidationError(u'Email addresses must be unique.')
        return email
```

Put something like that in the `forms.py` where you have the registration form.

Comment: Thanks, this is really great, but the password change issue is the main one, as its an important part of my page. Please let me know if anybody is able to solve it

Comment: @BobStone still working on it. Just wanted to pass on what I had.

Comment: Hey, I was wondering also if there is some way to make the email be checked when editing the profile too, once logged in. I seem to be getting an error when using the same method if editing the profile.

Comment: @BobStone presumably you could put the same function in your profile editing form.

Comment: You would just need to modify it to ensure that it is not the email address of the current logged in user.

Comment: Yeah, I tried that and I'm getting a type error: unhashable type: 'set'

Comment: @BobStone I'm going to recommend that you create a separate question for debugging for that as handling three issues in one question is getting messy and I don't know the answer for that offhand, so others may be needed.

Comment: @BobStone solved it. See the latest answer I added.

Answer (score 0):

for the email portion of your question:

views.py

```
email = self.cleaned_data.get('email')
foo = User.objects.filter(email=email)
if foo:
    return error
else:
***carry forth with saving the new user***
```

the 'if foo' will see if a user exists in the db with the email address given. If so, return error. If not carry forth with code.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the form problem.

You need to change:

```
<input placeholder="Password" id="id_password" name="password" type="password" class="form-control">
<input placeholder="Confirm Password" id="id_password2" name="password2" type="password" class="form-control">
```

To this:

```
<input placeholder="Password" name="new_password1" required id="id_new_password1" type="password" class="form-control">
<input placeholder="Confirm Password" name="new_password2" required id="id_new_password2"
type="password" class="form-control">
```

What is happening is that your `name` entries are wrong, which causes the form to fail validation in general in the default password reset view and get returned with a generic error.

Just swap those out and the form should work fine.